# How can I add CSS to grandchild pages in an unordered list on Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I've set up Wordpress menus via PHP, so I'm not directly setting up an unordered list with HTML. I've managed to set up a submenu for child pages, which appears when hovering over the main menu items. I'm having difficulty with doing the same for the children of the subpages, or "grandchild pages" in other words.

The css class/ID for my sub menu unordered list is:

```
nav.main-menu#header ul ul
```

I would have thought that it followed that the submenu for that would be:

```
nav.main-menu#header ul ul ul
```

but this doesn't seem to be working.

My CSS code code for the whole menu is:

```
nav.main-menu#header ul{
display:block;
padding:0;
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:0px;
list-style:none; 
}

nav.main-menu#header ul li {
float:left;
padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
margin-left: 45px;
}

nav.main-menu#header ul li a { 
font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica; 
font-size: 12.5px;
letter-spacing: 0.5px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav.main-menu#header ul li:first-child { margin-left:0px; }

nav.main-menu#header ul li.current-menu-item a:visited,
nav.main-menu#header ul li.current-menu-item a:link { color:#A084BD; }

/* CHILD PAGE MENU */

nav.main-menu#header ul ul { 
position:absolute; 
left: -999em; 
}

nav.main-menu#header ul li:hover ul {
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 3px; 
border-top-color: #A084BD;
z-index:10;
left:auto;
width: 180px;
height:auto;
margin:20px 0px 0px 0px;
box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), 0 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

nav.main-menu#header ul li ul li {
padding:0px;
margin-left:0px;
width:100%;
}

nav.main-menu#header ul li ul li a {
display: block;
padding: 20px 0px 20px 10px;
background-color:#ffffff;
transition: 800ms padding-left, .2s background-color, .2s color;

font-size:11.5px;
letter-spacing: 0.5px;
line-height: 0px;
color: #b8b8b8;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav.main-menu#header ul li ul li a:hover { 
padding-left: 15px; 
background-color:#ededed;
color: #9a9a9a;
}
```

My PHP function is:

```
function register_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary Menu', 'theme_wp' ),    
            'header' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
            'footer' => __( 'Footer Menu' )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_menus' );
```

My header is:

```
<header class="header">
    <!-- LOGOS -->
    <a href="#">
        <img class="standard logo" src="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Lucie_Averill_Photography_Logo-2.png">
        <img class="white logo" src="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Lucie_Averill_Photography_Logo_White.png"></a>
    <!-- LOGOS -->
    <img class="menu button" src="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Menu.png">
    <!-- HEADER NAVIGATION MENU -->
    <nav class="header-nav">
        <div class="menu-header-menu-container">
            <ul id="menu-header-menu" class="menu">
                <li id="menu-item-463">
                    <a href="#">WORK</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-584"><a href="#">LANDSCAPES</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-473"><a href="#">SEASCAPES</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-478"><a href="#">MACRO</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-477"><a href="#">CITIES</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-475"><a href="#">LONG EXPOSURE</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-480"><a href="#">MISCELLANEOUS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-10"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-464"><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-923">
                    <a href="#">SOCIAL</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-11"><a target="_blank" href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-924"><a href="#">INSTAGRAM</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-15"><a target="_blank" href="#">FLICKR</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                <li id="menu-item-14"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to appropriately nest your `ul` and `li` elements -- like so:

```
nav.main-menu#header ul li ul li ul
```

Because, in fact, the `ul` element isn't inside another `ul` element, it is inside the `li`.

Comment: Hi Ceili, thanks for that - I've tried it and it's now responding to CSS rules. For some reason though, it's not hiding to the left when I add "left:-999em;" like I have with the first sub menu. Do you know how I can get it to hide until I hover over its parent, after which it should display to the right hand side of the parent? At the moment, it's just floating about 50 px below it.

Comment: I'm having a hard time working out what you're asking. Do you think you could put it in to a jsfiddle or other tool for me?

Comment: I tried to get a jsfiddle to work but I'm not that experienced at coding and have been relying on the php to organise the html for me. I couldn't get it to link up with the css for some reason, sorry I couldn't be more helpful. I have an example here – http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/css-menu/demo/index.html  – if you hover over tutorials, then web design - the sub-sub menu appears perfectly lined up on the right of its parent.

Comment: Mine lines up on the right after using nav.main-menu#header ul ul ul { 
 postion:absolute; 
 display:none !important; 
 top:0px;
 left:100%;  – but it floats to the top for some reason.

Comment: Okay, I think I've solved this. The sub-submenu was taking properties from the submenu, which I've managed to fix by using !important. Not ideal really as I'd rather avoid using this where possible. I'm not sure why or how I've managed to overwrite the CSS properties of the main nav ul when editing the submenu ul, but had to use !important to overwrite it on the sub-submenu ul.

Comment: I'm glad you got it worked out :) If my answer was helpful to you solving your original question (unable to style nested `ul` elements), could you please accept the response?

Comment: Hi Ceili, sorry I thought I'd done this already. Have just done it now :)